# python pandas date time conversion to date

Tags: python, date, datetime, pandas

I am looking to convert datetime to date for a `pandas` `datetime` series.

I have listed the code below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()

df = pandas.io.parsers.read_csv("TestData.csv", low_memory=False)

df['PUDATE'] = pd.Series([pd.to_datetime(date) for date in df['DATE_TIME']])

df['PUDATE2'] = datetime.datetime.date(df['PUDATE'])  #Does not work
```

Can anyone guide me in right direction?

Comment: Might be a good start here--http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html

Comment: You should be able to just do `df = pd.read_csv("TestData.csv", parse_dates=['DATE_TIME'])` rather than all that code you're trying to use

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can access the `datetime` methods of a Pandas series by using the `.dt` methods (in a aimilar way to how you would access string methods using `.str`. For your case, you can extract the date of your datetime column as:

```
df['PUDATE'].dt.date
```

Comment: `df = pd.DataFrame()
df=pandas.io.parsers.read_csv("TestData.csv",low_memory=False)
df['PUDATE'] = \
pd.Series([pd.to_datetime(date) for date in df['ORIGIN_EXP_PKP_DATE_TIME']])                                                      df['test'] = df['PUDATE'].dt.date`

_AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'dt'_ is the error i get when i run the above code

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to specify the format for example

```
df['PUDATE2']=datetime.datetime.date(df['PUDATE'], format='%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
```

So you just need to know what format you are using

Comment: Running the code listed below I get the following error `AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'`       `df['PUDATE2']=datetime.datetime.date(df['PUDATE'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
df['PUDATE2'].head()`

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple way to get day of month, from a pandas

```
    #create a dataframe with dates as a string

    test_df = pd.DataFrame({'dob':['2001-01-01', '2002-02-02', '2003-03-03', '2004-04-04']})

    #convert column to type datetime
    test_df['dob']= pd.to_datetime(test_df['dob'])

    # Extract day, month , year  using dt accessor
    test_df['DayOfMonth']=test_df['dob'].dt.day
    test_df['Month']=test_df['dob'].dt.month
    test_df['Year']=test_df['dob'].dt.year
```